# How to convert .py file to .apk file on windows without using virtual machine

Tags: python, kivy

i have created a kivy app and i want to convert it to an apk file. I have searched about this and have found one method which is using 'buildozer' by creating a virtual machine on my windows. But my device does not support virtualization. Is there any other way to do so?? If yes, then please explain how to do that.
And is there a method to use virtual machine without enabling virtualization on windows??

Answer (score 0):

No you can't, buildozer works only on Linux system. But if you don't have linux you can use the free tier of online cloud platforms to execute and build your apk. The below video will give you the clear view of how.

> https://youtu.be/kcte8vcGMSU

But it will ask you for credit card. If you have it and okay with it you can do it online.

Hope this helps! Happy Learning:)